# While updating database using cron timeout occurs in plesk

Tags: php, cron, plesk

I am using plesk 11.0.9 version.I set a cron for updating the database.The cron file will run once's in a day.Each time I want a huge amount of data(around 20,000)updated to the database.But the cron file will run only for 5 min and time out occur.Due to this reason the database is not updated correctly.I used the following code inside the cron file.

```
<?php

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT id,detail_url,region,region_id FROM c_url_details_crone");

    while($ress=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {

    echo '---'. $city=$ress['region'];  echo "<br>";

    $url=$ress['detail_url'];

    $did=$ress['id'];

        require_once 'simplehtmldom_1_51/simple_html_dom.php';
        $html = file_get_html($url);
        foreach($html->find('h3[class=h3 z-address]') as $link)
        $data['address']= $link;
        foreach($html->find('h2[class=z-price brown]') as $pr)
        $data['priceH']= $pr;
        foreach($html->find('div[class=z-feature]') as $rooms)
        $data['room']=$rooms;
        foreach($html->find('div[class=z-description]') as $description)
        $data['description']=$description;


        $property1='';
        foreach($html->find('table[class=table-style]') as $property)
        {
        $property1=$property1. ','.$property;

        }
        $data['property']=$property1 ;

        foreach($html->find('table[class=table-style z-rooms]') as $extras)
        {
        $data['extras']=$extras;

        }
        foreach($html->find('li[class=z-mls]') as $listcode)
        {
        $data['listcode']=$listcode;
        }
        foreach($html->find('div[class=z-listing-by]') as $propertybrkr)
        {
        $data['propertybrkr']=$propertybrkr;
        } 

        foreach($html->find('div[class=small-12 columns flat-columns z-block]') as $propertyimages)
        $data['propertyimages']=$propertyimages;

         if(isset($propertyimages)){ $file_contents= $propertyimages;
    $img1='';
    foreach(@$file_contents->find('img') as $element)
    $img1=$img1. ','.$element->src;
      $imgeslidr=explode(',',$img1); 
     // print_r($imgeslidr);
      @$st0=implode(",",$imgeslidr);
      }
           $detls= explode(',',$property1);


        @$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(@$detls[1]);
@$cells = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
@$contents = array();
@$aa="";

foreach($cells as $cell)
{
    @$contents[] = $cell->nodeValue;
        $aa.=$cell->nodeValue.",";

}

@$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(@$detls[1]);
@$cells = $dom->getElementsByTagName('th');
@$contents = array();
$bb='';
foreach($cells as $cell)
{
    @$contents1[] = $cell->nodeValue;
    $bb.=$cell->nodeValue.",";
}

@$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(@$detls[3]);
@$cells = $dom->getElementsByTagName('th');
@$contents = array();
@$cc="";

foreach($cells as $cell)
{
    @$contents2[] = $cell->nodeValue;
        $cc.=$cell->nodeValue.",";

}

@$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(@$detls[3]);
@$cells = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
@$contents = array();
@$dd="";

foreach($cells as $cell)
{
    @$contents3[] = $cell->nodeValue;
        $dd.=$cell->nodeValue.",";

}

@$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(@$detls[4]);
@$cells = $dom->getElementsByTagName('th');
@$contents = array();
@$ff="";

foreach($cells as $cell)
{
    @$contents5[] = $cell->nodeValue;
        $ff.=$cell->nodeValue.",";

}

@$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(@$detls[3]);
@$cells = $dom->getElementsByTagName('thead');
@$contents = array();
@$gg="";

foreach($cells as $cell)
{
    @$contents6[] = $cell->nodeValue;
        $gg.=$cell->nodeValue.",";

}

@$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(@$detls[4]);
@$cells = $dom->getElementsByTagName('thead');
@$contents = array();
@$hh="";
foreach($cells as $cell)
{
    @$contents7[] = $cell->nodeValue;
            $hh.=$cell->nodeValue.",";

}

@$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(@$detls[2]);
@$cells = $dom->getElementsByTagName('thead');
@$contents = array();
@$uu="";
foreach($cells as $cell)
{
    @$contents8[] = $cell->nodeValue;
        $uu.=$cell->nodeValue.",";

}

@$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(@$detls[2]);
@$cells = $dom->getElementsByTagName('th');
@$contents = array();
@$jj="";

foreach($cells as $cell)
{
    @$contents9[] = $cell->nodeValue;
        $jj.=$cell->nodeValue.",";

}

@$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(@$detls[2]);
@$cells = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
@$contents = array();
@$kk="";

foreach($cells as $cell)
{
    @$contents10[] = $cell->nodeValue;
        $kk.=$cell->nodeValue.",";

}

@$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(@$extras);
@$cells = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
@$contents = array();
@$contss="";

foreach($cells as $cell)
{
    @$contentsss[] = $cell->nodeValue;
        $contss.=$cell->nodeValue."**#**";

}

 @$images1=$st0;
@$a1=$aa;
 @$b1=$bb;
@$c1=mysql_real_escape_string($cc);
@$d1=mysql_real_escape_string($dd);
@$f1=mysql_real_escape_string($ff);
@$g1=mysql_real_escape_string($gg);
@$h1=mysql_real_escape_string($hh);
@$i1=mysql_real_escape_string($uu);
@$j1=mysql_real_escape_string($jj);
@$k1=mysql_real_escape_string($kk);
@$l1=mysql_real_escape_string($contss);
@$decs=$description;

$c++;

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO house_moredetails_crone(city,durl,a,b,c,d,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,description,images)
VALUES('".$city."','".$url."','".$a1."','".$b1."','".$c1."','".$d1."','".$f1."','".$g1."','".$h1."','".$i1."','".$j1."','".$k1."','".$l1."','".$decs."','".$images1."')") ;

    mysql_query("DELETE  FROM c_url_details_crone WHERE id='$did'");
    }
?>
```

Is there any other better option other than the cron for updating database.Or by using cron is there any solution to update database without timeout.Waiting for your reply!!

Comment: have you tried  `set_time_limit(0)`... ???

Comment: After setting `set_time_limit(0)` don't forget to restart your apache